# Understanding the output layer formation of an LSTM unit in Keras

Tags: time-series, interpretation, lstm, keras

I'm struggling to get my head around how the output shape of an LSTM layer formed. How is the output unit value physically implemented in the layer?

For example, if I have an input shape of (128 x 6) with return_sequence=true andunits=10. How is the raw output of each LSTM unit converted into a (128x10) shaped output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty accurate
[Understanding LSTM Weights](https://medium.com/@shivajbd/understanding-input-and-output-shape-in-lstm-keras-c501ee95c65e)

TL;DR, the output shape is 3D with Return sequences True, because output for each timestamp is returned and
the output shape is 2D with Return sequences False, because output by last timestamp or LSTM unit is returned